# What "standard estimates for the laplacian" do the authors of this paper mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to follow the proof of lemma 2.1 in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0711.2408) paper.

**The setup.** Consider a solution $v$ to the nonlinear equation $$ -\Delta v = ic \partial_1 v + v(1-\vert v\vert^2) ~\mbox{on}~ \mathbb{R}^N$$ with finite energy, i.e., $$\Vert Dv \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)}+ \Vert 1-\vert v \vert^2 \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)} < \infty. $$ Here, $c$ is a real constant and $i$ the imaginary unit.

**The question.** The authors want to prove the following statement.

> There is a constant $K(c,k,N)>0$ such that $\Vert v \Vert_{C^k(\mathbb{R}^N)} \leq K(c,k,N), \forall k \in \mathbb{R}.$

All they say is: "One invokes standard estimates for the laplacian".

What standard estimates do they mean? What, precisely, is the argument here?

**More information.** I don't know if this helps, but from the first part of the lemma in the paper, we already know the following:

- $\Vert 1 - \vert v \vert \Vert_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)} \leq \max \lbrace 1, \frac{c}{2} \rbrace$
- $\Vert \nabla v \Vert_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)} \leq K(N) \left( 1+ \frac{c^2}{4} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$
- v is smooth and bounded.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect they mean the estimates on the Newtonian potential (see Gilbarg-Trudinger, Chapter 4, Thm 4.5, for example). The idea is that if you have some control (in, say, the $L^\infty$ sense) over the right hand side, then you can control the $C^1$ norm of $u$. If you have some control over the right hand side in the $C^\alpha$ sense, then you can control the $C^{2,\alpha}$ norm of $u$.

Subsequently, to control higher derivatives of $u$, you differentiate the equation to get an elliptic equation involving the Laplacian on appropriate derivatives of $u$, and in this manner iteratively use the estimates on lower order derivatives.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that and get back to you!

Comment: Indeed, the second estimate in Gilbarg-Trudinger's theorem 4.5 is what I need. But my functions (in contrast to the functions in the theorem) do not have compact support. Am I missing something? In theorem 4.6 they drop this assumption, but then need $f \in C^\alpha$, which I do not know.

Comment: Don't you? I mean, you get that $v$ and thus $1-v$ are both Lipschitz, and that should give you the right hand side - the term in the first derivative is a linear term and could be incorporated into the operator. So I suppose technically you are using something closer in spirit to the Schauder estimates in G-T Chapter 6, but with a complex coefficient ....